# What's the word for not wanting to repeat a semantic atom?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

In other words, what's the word for not wanting to repeat a word? I find attempts to avoid repeating a word are generally ham-fisted and unnatural. I know there is a word for the act of not repeating a word, but I can't remember what it is.

Comment: Could you give us a sentence as an exemplar (especially the "ham-fisted and unnatural" type)?

Comment: @rhetorician I thought I had in the title of the question. Here's another: "He liked a drink, but that night had had one beverage too many." I'd have written: "He liked a drink, but that night had had one drink too many." But some people think it's somehow bad style to repeat a word and try to find a synonym instead. My kids sometimes ask me, "Dad, what's another word for such and such?" I ask why and get told, I've already written "such-and-such" in the previous sentence. I need another word to avoid repeating it. To which I reply, "no, you don't."

Comment: Well, in your precise example I would probably have written "He liked a drink, but that night had had one too many." since it's obvious what is meant even if one dispenses entirely with the noun in the secondary clause. Given that Just A Minute (the radio comedy quiz) sets so many standards, I'd say the term 'avoidance of repetition' suits your purpose despite being three words and not one.

Comment: You say, "Ungulates from eastern New York which are bullied by large cows from Erie County, in turn pester bison from the Niagara Region."  I say, "Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo, buffalo Buffalo buffalo."  Same thing.

Comment: Not being familiar with the term "semantic atom," I didn't associate it with a "ham-fisted" attempt at avoiding repetition. (At least I'm willing to admit my ignorance. Many others would pretend to know what it means and not leave a comment.) Don

Comment: @rhetorician 'semantic atom' was my ham-fisted synonym for 'word'.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. As I said in my last comment, I was ignorant as to what a "semantic atom" was and is. Thought: Would a sentence qualify as a semantic molecule? Don

Comment: "Foolish rule, imposed blindly."  Though I suppose that's not a single word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Elegant Variation**

Defined by Oxford Dictionaries Online as "The stylistic fault of studiedly finding different ways to denote the same thing in a piece of writing, merely to avoid repetition."

Comment: That's the one I was trying to remember. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The word you may be looking for is ***Conduplicatio***

> #### Conduplicatio
>
> noun, *Latin*
>
> 1. A rhetorical term for the repetition of one or more words in successive clauses.
> 2. The repetition of a word in various places throughout a paragraph.
>
> *"The **inherent** vice of capitalism is the unequal sharing of blessings; the **inherent** virtue of socialism is the equal sharing of miseries."*
>
> *"And the **world** said, 'Disarm, disclose, or face serious consequences'—and therefore, we worked with the **world**, we worked to make sure that Saddam Hussein heard the message of the **world**." - George W. Bush*

([grammar.about.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/conduplicatio.htm))

Or, thinking of the inverse of Conduplicatio, *Dissimilation* may be usable.

> #### Dissimilation
>
> *noun*
>
> 1. The act of making or becoming unlike.

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dissimilation))

While **Dissimilation** is usually used in phonetics, not grammar, it may be adaptable to function for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you. But that is the opposite of the word I was trying to remember. I'm trying to remember the word for 'avoiding repetition'.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to [grammar.about.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/monologoterm.htm) (for whatever *that*'s worth), the term "**monologophobia**" was coined by New York Times editor Theodore M. Bernstein in 1965.  That page defines the word as

> A fear of using a word more than once in a single sentence or paragraph.

Comment: Sounds more like it means a fear of monologues.

Answer (score 3):

The ***Horror aequi* principle** is one term used in linguistics:

> the horror aequi principle ... involves the widespread (and presumably universal) tendency to avoid the use of formally (near-)identical and (near-)adjacent grammatical elements or structures
>
> <sub>[Determinants of grammatical variation in English and the formation / confirmation of linguistic hypotheses by means of internet data](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/rodopi/lang/2006/00000059/00000001/art00011)</sub>